# system V semaphores C

Tags: c

I’m trying to use the system V semaphores, but I'm not able to control their value with semop, and so what they do. I should have three total processes that alternate with each other with semaphores that regulate the game turns. If anyone can help me with a practical example I would be very grateful.

```
PROCESS1
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>

#define KSEM 2292 
#define KKSEM 9922


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

 struct sembuf x;

  x.sem_num = 0;
  x.sem_op = -1;
  x.sem_flg = 0;

   int idserver, idclient;
    int val1 = 0, val2 = 0;

// declaration
    idserver = semget (KSEM, 1, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666);
    idclient = semget (KKSEM, 1, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666);

    if (idserver <0){
        perror("idserver: ");
        _exit(1);
    }
    if (idclient <0){
        perror("idclient: ");
        _exit(1);
    }
    printf("hello1");
// intializing
    semctl(idserver, 0, SETVAL, val1); //server set to 0
    semctl(idclient, 0, SETVAL, val2); //client set to 0
    printf("ciaoserver1");
    int a;
    a = semop (idserver, &x, 1);
    printf("waiting for client...");
    printf("VALUE SERVER: %i \n", a);
    

return 0;
}
PROCESS2

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>

#define KSEM 2292 
#define KKSEM 9922

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

 struct sembuf x;

  x.sem_num = 0;
  x.sem_op = 1;
  x.sem_flg = 0;

  struct sembuf y;

  y.sem_num = 0;
  y.sem_op = 0;
  y.sem_flg = 0;

   struct sembuf z;

  y.sem_num = 0;
  y.sem_op = -2;
  y.sem_flg = 0;

   int idserver, idclient;
   int val1 = 0, val2 = 0;

   // declaration
idserver = semget (KSEM, 1, IPC_EXCL | 0666);
if(idserver < 0) {
        perror("idserver: ");
        _exit(1);
 }

idclient = semget (KKSEM, 1, IPC_EXCL | 0666);
if(idclient<0){
        perror("idclient: ");
        _exit(1);
    }

// initialize
semctl(idserver, 0, SETVAL, val1); //server set to 0
semctl(idclient, 0, SETVAL, val2); //client set to 0
printf("CLIENT1");
int a;

    a = semop (idclient, &x, 1);
    semop (idclient, &y, 1);
    semop (idclient, &x, 1);
    semop (idclient, &y, 1);
    semop (idserver, &y, 1);

    printf("VALUE CLIENT 1: %i", a);
   

   
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I'm not able to control their value with semop" ... can you show us? I'm not entirely sure what your code is supposed to do, so it's hard to tell whether it does it. Please make a [mre] that just demonstrates your problem. The best format is: "code, I expected X to happen, but Y happened".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.